# Netbeans: Mem-Usage always higher and higher every I compiled

Tags: java, memory, memory-management, netbeans, ram

I'm using Netbeans. Every i compiled java.exe memory usage in task manager always higher and higher. And It isn't higher until i compile some java again.

For example i compile and run **test1.java**
java.exe 151,000kb

run it again
java.exe 165.000kb

waiting... i mean run it
and it still
java.exe 165.000kb

but when i run it again
java.exe 170.000kb

When i close my netbeans memory usage for java.exe disappear.
I'm using Windows XP

I coding to make 2D Game with Full-Screen.

How to fix that?

Comment: What's java.exe? I mean, what is it running? Netbeans has its own netbeans.exe, so I assume this is your program running. But you don't mention running it, only compiling, so I'm quite confused. If you actually run it, then please check that you terminate it properly too.

Comment: If you are instantiating a `JFrame`, you should dispose the frame when the program terminates using JFrame's `setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE)` method

Comment: @Alpine, actually it does the opposite thing: terminates the program when the frame closes. Still, it's a good advice for most single-window GUI programs, though.

Comment: @Sergey: I mean running it after compile it. Sorry it has mistake.
@Alpine: Yes i "JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE" it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that's normal. Try to run and exit the compiled `jar` file from command line multiple times, and see if you get the same phenomenon:

```
java -jar C:\myPath\myJar.jar
```

You can find the compiled `jar` in the `dist` folder of your project.

Remember NetBeans runs as `java.exe` too.

Comment: Yes i know that. If i compile my project several times. The memory usage expand till > 300MB. And it using >95 CPU(left-next to memory-usage). And of course it make my computer run slow.